# How to copy email in INBOX into important mailbox with imaplib?

Tags: python-3.x, imaplib

I am in python3.4 .

```
import imaplib
import email
user="xxxx"
password="yyyy"
con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
con.login(user,password)
con.list()
```

`('OK', [b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"', b'(\\Noselect \\HasChildren) "/" "[Gma
    il]"', b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Junk) "/" "[Gmail]/&V4NXPpCuTvY-"', b'(\\HasNoChildr
    en \\Trash) "/" "[Gmail]/&XfJSIJZkkK5O9g-"', b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Flagged) "/" "
    [Gmail]/&XfJSoGYfaAc-"', b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Sent) "/" "[Gmail]/&XfJT0ZCuTvY-"'
    , b'(\\HasNoChildren \\All) "/" "[Gmail]/&YkBnCZCuTvY-"', b'(\\HasNoChildren \\D
    rafts) "/" "[Gmail]/&g0l6Pw-"', b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Important) "/" "[Gmail]/&kc
    2JgQ-"'])`

I want to copy all the email in INBOX into my Important mailbox.

```
con.select("INBOX")
typ,data=con.search(None,'ALL')
num=data[0].split()
for item in num:
    con.copy(item,"[Gmail]/&kc2JgQ-]")
```

error message:  ('NO', [b'[TRYCREATE] No folder [Gmail]/\xe9\x87\x8d\xe8\xa6\x81] (Failure)'])

```
for item in num:
    con.copy(item,"[Gmail]/Important")
```

error message:     ('NO', [b'[TRYCREATE] No folder [Gmail]/Important (Failure)'])

```
for item in num:
    con.copy(item,"\\Important")
```

error message:    imaplib.error: COPY command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

How to copy email in INBOX into important mailbox with imaplib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
con.copy(item,"[Gmail]/&kc2JgQ-]")
```

… you've got a stray `]` on the end. The string you copied it from looks like this:

```
"[Gmail]/&kc2JgQ-"
```